# How to use JVM RMI registry when many Application Servers and alone JVM

Tags: java, jboss, jvm, rmi

The situation: one server machine with some installed Application Servers (JBoss). JVM is alone for the whole machine and it's used by every server. 
Every server has his own RMI stub which is registered in RMI registry while server is starting. But, for correct work of RMI it's needed to define Java property `java.rmi.server.codebase` = path to jar file with classes for stubing. This is the main problem: when many servers use one JVM, but defined path is to only one application server directory. Thus, RMI clients can't connect to different servers and invoke different versions of remote interfaces.

My view is there're the following ways:

1. Create separate RMI registry in every application server (in JBoss), but I don't know how it makes?
2. Add into the name of stub sign of application server (e.g. host:port) and then from client lookup jndi name of needed server+stub?

Are there any other variants? Maybe someone already met with such problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) is your only choice. It is done with `LocateRegistry.createRegistry()`, unless JBoss has a way to configure it permanently. You will have to use separate ports per Registry.

(2) doesn't even make sense to me without further explanation, unless it is really a continuation of (1).

Comment: Yes, I thought about variant with different ports per Registry. I'll look to this way, thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, I defined that in one JVM cannot be created more than one RMI registries. And JBoss hasn't own registry implementation, so there's cannot be created separate registries...
Now there is variant with registering different stubs with different names (depends on appserver) in one RMI registry, but was occurred new problem: throws ClassNotFoundException because for normal working RMI is needed to define Java property java.rmi.server.codebase. If I specified this property to one app server, then from the rest of servers I cannot bind stub due to this exception.

Comment: You've been able to have multiple Registries per JVM since about 1.5, as long as they're all on different ports: at least JRMP Registries.